# I need an eVC++ data type equivalent to __int64

Tags: data-structures, types, long-integer, evc

Is there a data type in [eVC++](http://www.google.com/search?q=embedded+visual+c%2B%2B) that is the equivalent of [`__int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx)? None of the aliases compile. And I cannot find any of the long types in `Math.h`.

A third party library would also be acceptable.

Comment: What is eVC++?  The article you referenced doesn't have "evc" in the text anywhere.

Comment: Embedded Visual C++. The Wikipedia article noted it in a bullet point in the History section (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#History). I updated the link to Google... I can't find a product page.

Comment: No longer a seperate product. Superceded by Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using EVC++ 4.0...

You'll first need to make sure you have the Pocket PC 2003 SDK installed.  If you are on win mobile 5.0 and up and are still attempting to use EVC++4.0 I will fight you (Ron Burgundy).  The PPC 2003 SDK can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=9996B314-0364-4623-9EDE-0B5FBB133652&displaylang=en).

After it's install, update the linker to find the newly installed SDK header files with the macro definition of LONGLONG.  To do this:

1. Tools -> options
2. Directories tab -> make sure the third drop down reads "include files"
3. Add the path -> "C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce420\POCKET PC 2003\Include\Armv4"
4. Make sure to #include winnt.h in your class.  In that header you will find the definition of LONGLONG which is an _int64

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the [LargeInt](http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/largeint.h.html) library in eVC++? IIRC this was a standard lib bundled with VC 6.0.  VC 6.0 did not support `__int64` natively.

Answer (score 0):

"long long" is a synonym for "__int64" in VC++... maybe that works?

Comment: Nope. None of the aliases, `long long` nor `signed long long` are available.